# Run a subroutine if a cell's date is after today

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Im trying to get some vba code to run if cell l1's date has already passed. However im am getting a run time error 91.
The code i am using is as follows but something is not quite right with the variables which unfortunately despite my efforts i cannot solve.

```
Sheets("HAULAGE PLANNER").Activate
Dim FoundCell As Object

Set FoundCell = Range("L1").Find(what:=Date)

    If FoundCell = ("<= Today") Then

   Run.Module1.nextweek

    Else: Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the text of run-time error 91, and what line does it appear on?

Comment: If you are looking at a specific cell, you don't need to `.find()`.  `If Range("L1").Value <= Now() Then` woudl suffice.

Comment: Runtimeerror is happening on this bit of code ```If FoundCell = ("<= Today") Then```

Comment: Using the If range bypasses the runtimeerrror however it won't run the module 1 just bypasses that line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will move my comment to an answer.

---

If you are looking at a specific cell, you don't need to .find(). If Range("L1").Value <= Now() Then would suffice.

You may also need to check that `L1` is in fact a date, so you would use [IsDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) to check.

Third point, don't use activate... you can just qualify the `Sheets()` for the cell reference.

Mock-up of your code with above changes (untested):

```
Dim DateCell As Range
Set DateCell = Sheets("HAULAGE PLANNER").Range("L1")
If Not IsDate(DateCell.Value) Then Exit Sub
If DateCell.Value <= Now() Then Application.Run("Module1.nextweek")
```

Comment: Or just `Module1.nextweek`

Comment: Genius Cyril. Thank you so much

Comment: @J.Counter if this resolved your issue, please mark as answered (check mark left of my response).  That will get this off of the "unanswered" questions list to help more folks get the help they need!